# Вывод случаных пользователей

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте, вот хочу написать код который будет вытаскивать из базы 7 случайных пользователей,вроде написал, но не так как мне нужно, он выводит одного пользователя 7 раз, обновляю другого 7 раз, как сделать чтобы сразу выводил 7 случайных пользователей!

PHP Код:

```
<?
$race_g_sql = "SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 7";
$race_res_g = mysql_query($race_g_sql) or die(mysql_error());
$row_g = mysql_fetch_array($race_res_g);
$nick_g = $row_g['nick'];

for($i=0; $i<=7; $i++){
echo $nick_g;
?>
```

Comment: @ромыч, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: Distinct добавьте перед *

Answer (score 5):

```
while($row_g = mysql_fetch_array($race_res_g)) {
 $nick = $row_g['nick'];

 echo "$nick <hr />";
}
```

Comment: спасибо огромное!